# AggregateResult Count help

Tags: apex, aggregate, count

Sorry to bother you on a Saturday, but i need some help 
This is a two part question, so please be patient .I have created a fieldset on the account object called “HistoryTracking”.

1) I would like to count how many times the fields within the fieldset “HistoryTracking” is not null
2) count how many times there is a field

So For example in my sandbox, i have created four accounts. The field website is populated three out of four accounts
Desired  results;

Field  :Website
Populated :3
Total count : 4
I have wrote the following below( which more than likely wrong as my first time writing an aggregate query) but as you can see i have  hardcoded “Website” Into the query.  I have approx 10 fields in the fieldset and i don’t want to manually hard code these into the query

```
AggregateResult[] ARs
= [SELECT count(Id) myCount, website
  FROM HistoryTracking
  GROUP BY website];
```

Looking forward to your response

Comment: With that approach you will have to query multiple times, I would probabyl query all records once and then check if they are populated inside a loop keeping in the count in a map <string, integer>, where the keys will be the field names.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the two parts of your question but the code below hopefully covers at least part of what you are looking for.

Because [count(fieldName)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_count.htm) is available, some simple dynamic SOQL can be used. The `countNonNullFields` method in this code (move it to some other class to use it) does what I think you want:

```
@isTest
private class DynamicAggregationTest {
    @isTest(SeeAllData=true)
    static void test() {
        String[] fields = new String[] {'Name', 'Birthdate', 'Email', 'Phone'};
        system.debug('>>> counts=' + countNonNullFields('Contact', fields));
    }
    private static Map<String, Integer> countNonNullFields(String type, String[] fields) {
        String[] selects = new String[] {};
        for (String f : fields) {
            selects.add('count(' + f + ') ' + f);
        }
        Map<String, Integer> counts = new Map<String, Integer>();
        String soql = 'select ' + String.join(selects, ', ') + ' from ' + type;
        // One row only is returned
        for (AggregateResult ar : Database.query(soql)) {
            for (String f : fields) {
                counts.put(f, (Integer) ar.get(f));
            }
        }
        return counts;
    }
}
```

as it executes this dynamic SOQL query:

```
select count(Name) Name, count(Birthdate) Birthdate, count(Email) Email, count(Phone) Phone
from Contact
```

and returns a map of field names to non-null counts. The count for "Name" provides the total row count as "Name" is never null.

If you use this code, you should get rid of the `SeeAllData=true` in the test and instead insert test data and add asserts for the expected results.

**PS**

Doing some more testing of this I hit an "Internal Salesforce.com Error" a couple of times and also found that lookup fields are not supported. So proceed with caution.